# How to search user located in a city and has certain skills i.e. in Android development?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow

I need an expert can help me in Android development. I would search for user located here in Budapest with Android experience.

Comment: Stack Overflow (which this site is not) is not a social network. There are not that many ways to search for users.

Comment: We do, however, operate a job board. You can buy the candidate search product from us - http://business.stackoverflow.com/careers

Comment: I would suggest this as a feature request. In my opinion SO is a social network.

Comment: And I would decline it. This is not what Stack Overflow is for and about. If you are looking for a developer to work with you - you can use our job board, where there are people who *are* looking for work.

Comment: ^He works here... so if anyone knows what SO (and the larger SE network) is about, it's him. :D

Comment: One of the main strengths of Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow are that they are not social networks at all.

Comment: As a note, having the search function would be pointless as there's no way to actually contact said user... there's no messaging system and lots of users don't use chat, so unless they have an email address in their user info page, knowing that they have knowledge in a subject area and that they live in a particular city is pointless... and, no... commenting on one of their posts is *not* an acceptable way of "contacting" someone.

Comment: @Catija there is many way to communicate without "message system" I can just write him a comment, or check email address, or just check his username on Twitter etc. For me every site is a Social Network where users communicating this or that way, with Question and Answers, or an other controlled way.

Comment: ... did you actually read my entire comment?

Comment: You can use SEDE for this. No need for something built in.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The user search is based on user display names or reputation.

There is no location based search - partly because we don't ask our registered users for their location nor do we validate it.

Stack Overflow is not a social network - the Q&A side is very specifically for people to ask and answer questions. We don't focus on the individuals who post.

Most (all?) of the people on the site appreciate that they cannot be contacted by strangers willy nilly - a location based search would go against that.

---

The way to contact a developer on Stack Overflow for work is through our [job board](http://business.stackoverflow.com/careers) - this has developers who have indicated that they are open to being contacted in this manner.